# textbox won't accept ENTER in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a few controls in a Form, so I read and create a Event in the form that allows me to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to change the focus to another control. Here's the code:

```
private void frSeleccionEL_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            Control nextControl = this.GetNextControl(ActiveControl, !e.Shift);
            if (nextControl != null)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                if (!(nextControl is Label))
                {
                    nextControl.Focus();
                }
                else //the next control is currently a label
                {
                    nextControl = this.GetNextControl(ActiveControl, true);
                    while (nextControl != null)
                    {
                        nextControl.Focus();
                        if (!(nextControl is Label))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        nextControl = this.GetNextControl(ActiveControl, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In the textbox where it's not working, I have code for only numbers. Here's the code:

```
private void txtLocal_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //Para obligar a que sólo se introduzcan números
        if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) //permitir teclas de control como retroceso
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //el resto de teclas pulsadas se desactivan
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }      
    }
```

My problem is when I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in this control nothing happens, like <kbd>ENTER</kbd> was never pressed, because the event keypress for this control doesn't fire.

I deleted the control and remade it and the problem remains.

I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: You need to set the Multiline property to True.

Comment: How are you adding your KeyPress EventHandler to your Textbox? you have 1 of 2 ways , either use the designer or add the handler to your textbox in code.  i.e.  txtLocal.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(txtLocal_KeyPress);

Comment: I added the keyPress EventHandler with the designer, if i pressed any key the event work but if i pressed ENTER don't do nothing

Answer (score 1):

Your first code is too long and we don't need it. If you want to turn Enter keypress into a Tab switch, using `SelectNextControl` method of your form. I can see your `txtLocal_KeyPress` does nothing with switching tab, so how you knew what happened or not. `e.Handled` only helps suppress the key press event or not. I guess your `TextBox` has `Multiline = true;` and you want to suppress the Enter keypress, instead switch to the next control, otherwise you don't have to suppress the Enter keypress in `TextBox` with `Multiline=false`. This short code will help you:

```
private void txtLocal_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){
    if(e.KeyChar == 13)//Enter{
        e.Handled = true;
        SelectNextControl(txtLocal, true, true, true, true);
    }
}
```

That's all to solve your problem.
I'm not sure if you know how to register a `KeyPress` event handler with your TextBox.KeyPress event, so I add this here to help you in that case:

```
txtLocal.KeyPress += txtLocal_KeyPress;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private void txtLocal_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //Para obligar a que sólo se introduzcan números
        if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) )
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

please use this code on form key down this will give you better performance

```
private void frSeleccionEL_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
       ProcessTabKey(true);
     }
}
```

please make sure you have set tab index on all of your control.

and then unchanged your text changed event code. it will be better if you use a custom text box instead of writing this code on all of your form.

Comment: with the ProcessTabKey do the same, and i set all the tad index, with the custom text box you refer the MaskedTextBox or is another control

Comment: customer text box means ,you just extend a text box and customize as you want. <public partial class NumericTextbox : TextBox>

Answer (score 0):

Try this ......

```
private void txtLocal_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //Para obligar a que sólo se introduzcan números
        if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || asc(e.KeyChar)==13)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) //permitir teclas de control como retroceso
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //el resto de teclas pulsadas se desactivan                
                e.Handled = true;

            }
        }      
    }
```

Comment: not working, is like enter never pressed but TAB yes, I don't know what is wrong. when debugged the code in the event of keypressed, if i pressed any key the event work but if i pressed ENTER don't do nothing

Comment: @JoséGordilloLópez .. Not so sure about your real situation .. but you can try again ..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to commit your changes with the enter key, assuming you want to update your data bindings, but stay in the control you can use the following code

```
private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(e.KeyCode == (char)Keys.Enter)
   {
      TextBox.DataBindings[0].WriteValue();
      dataBindingSource.ResetCurrentItem();
      TextBox.Select(TextBox.Text.Length, 0);
      e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

The important part there is WriteValue() which commits the changes before the databind event fires. If you want other controls to update on your form after committing the changes, the ResetCurrentItem() will do this. Also, this code just commits the first binding value, but if you have multiple bindings you can step through them with a foreach loop and WriteValue() all of them or whatever. The TextBox.Select() line just keeps your cursor where you left it after pressing enter.